# What design patterns to be used in this class diagram?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

I'm working on the application to create class diagram of video store. In that customer may subscribe with retailer to be notified of new releases. Can I use observer design pattern for this requirement? And some of the requirements for the application is:

1. the ability to create and retrieve movies for every category
2. retailer sends 10% discount voucher for randomly selected customers everyday

I did this class diagram without any pattern which is straightforward.
I want to improve this by applying design patterns to the diagram.
Any suggestions what patterns can be used?

Comment: Design patterns help solve commonly occurring problems in the technical implementation of a system. Asking what patterns to apply to functional requirements, in my humble opinion, is not the right way of approaching your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As scriptfromscratch said, this: I did this class diagram without any pattern which is straightforward. I want to improve this by applying design patterns to the diagram. Any suggestions what patterns can be used? is a very bad idea...
The "benefit" of design patterns, is that you can name things you've encountered while solving your problem, so it's easier to transmit what you've done. There is no such thing as "improving something by applying design patterns". You are going in the path of abusing design patterns, which is a very bad idea.
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DesignPatternsConsideredHarmful
http://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/the-abuse-of-design-patterns-in-writing-a-hello-world-program/

Comment: How to implement the 'retailer sends 10% discount voucher for randomly selected customers everyday' requirement? I'm stuck with that